# Django Tutorial - Writing your first Django app, part 2, I'm trying to migrate but it shows "No migrations to apply."

Tags: python, django

I just started learning Django through the tutorial from Djangoproject.
I'm trying to migrate but it shows "No migrations to apply" in terminal where it supposed to show "Applying polls.0001_initial... OK."
And don't know where I made mistakes, could you please help?
Thank you.

[Terminal]

```
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: admin, auth, contenttypes, polls, sessions
Running migrations:
  No migrations to apply.
```

[mysite/polls/models.py]

```
from django.db import models

class Question(models.Model):
    question_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')


class Choice(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    choice_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    votes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

[migrations/0001_initial.py]

```
from django.db import migrations, models
import django.db.models.deletion


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    initial = True

    dependencies = [
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='Choice',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
                ('choice_text', models.CharField(max_length=200)),
                ('votes', models.IntegerField(default=0)),
            ],
        ),
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='Question',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
                ('question_text', models.CharField(max_length=200)),
                ('pub_date', models.DateTimeField(verbose_name='date published')),
            ],
        ),
        migrations.AddField(
            model_name='choice',
            name='question',
            field=models.ForeignKey(on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE, to='polls.Question'),
        ),
    ]
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/intro/tutorial02/

I'm using python 3.7.2 with anaconda.

Comment: Did you install the app in the settings file?

Comment: Yes, I think I did. If this is correct. INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'polls.apps.PollsConfig',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]

Comment: Deleted everything and started again and it worked. Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

It might sound dumb but did you refresh your app? I mean example: on VSCode on the file sidebar you can right click and select refresh or click on the refresh tab by the create file tab.  I have had it not show my new migrations before and had to refresh to see them.

Comment: I deleted everything and started again and it worked. Thank you so much for your help.